# How to get the sum of three numbers User entered in the Prompt window? JS

Tags: javascript

How to get the sum of three numbers  User entered in the **Prompt** window???.

For example, the user entered 123 (1+2+3)

```
console.log = 6
```

Comment: What window are you referring to as the "Promt" window? Also, it is expected that you do some research and make some attempts.

Comment: window.confirm. @HereticMonkey I would assume

Comment: @Dalorzo That is certainly an assumption. I would assume `window.prompt`. But I was asking the OP.

Comment: var userEnter =+prompt( );

Comment: `user=prompt("enter numbers");
console.log(user.split("").reduce((acc,cv)=>acc+=+cv,0));`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You've stated user enters, for example, `123`, and that you want to break that into digits and log the sum.  So:

```js
console.log(
  prompt("enter a series of digits, such as 123")
  .split("")
  .reduce((acc,cv)=>acc+=+cv,0)
);
```

If you meant, for example, `1+2+3`, then:

```js
console.log(
  prompt("enter addition expression, such as: 1+2+3")
  .split("+")
  .reduce((acc,cv)=>acc+=+cv,0)
);
```

Comment: How is this different to the answer already posted?

Comment: console.log(
  prompt("enter addition expression, such as: 1+2+3")
  .split("+")
  .reduce((acc,cv)=>acc+=+cv,0)
);

Comment: This option is much more convenient

Comment: Thanks for the time

Comment: Thank you, @An.88!
Please select my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Store user input in promptValue.
let promptValue = prompt("Please enter a sum", "1+1+1");
// Remove only plus symbol. Everything else will result correctly in NaN
promptValue = promptValue.replaceAll("+", "");
// Reduce into the sum and output in the log.
console.log(promptValue.split('').reduce( (v,n)=> (v) + (+n) ,0));
```

A simple for loop that takes the character at each position of the entered string should do the trick.

**Edit 1: added comments**

**Edit 2: fixed the issue with plus character**

**Edit 3: accept with plus Or without without loop**

Comment: This does not solve the issue if I enter 1+2+3

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
Well this issue needs to be solved without a loop :(

Comment: if number is a double digit?

Comment: @Dalorzo read the question again.

Comment: Only from three-digit numbers

Comment: @Dalorzo wrong, it removes the plus. Other responses don't.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the first solution but I would like add a regex to get only the numbers

```js
console.log(
  prompt("enter numbers")
  .replace(/\D/g, "")
  .split("")
  .reduce((acc,cv)=>acc+=+cv,0)
);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.